# R plot color intensity regarding density

Tags: r

I have a count plot in R with 3 different values on the legend (1000, 2000, 3000). What I want to do is to color them in such a way, that the color of every next value is more intense. So 1000 would be very pale and 3000 would be very intense. I don't know whether it's a case of alpha or coloring, I'm pretty new to R overall. However I couldn't find any insight in the documentation. I'm using geom_count in ggplot2 for the plot.

What I have now:
[image: what i have]

What I want:
[image: what i want]

Any help would be very appreciated!

Comment: Can you share the code you are currently using to create the plot? If I remember correctly you can use the color keyword in `ggplot` to color the points based on a value.

Comment: Sure. That's what I'm using: ggplot(data, aes(x, y)) + geom_count(alpha=0.5, color="blue")

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use the `color` keyword in the `aes` function to refer to the variable based on which you want to color your points (see also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45883383/9435355) on stackoverflow):

```
ggplot(data, aes(x, y)) + geom_count(aes(color=..n..), alpha=0.5)
```